# How can i send the data to an API defined in WSDL PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am new to this whole WSDL thing and I am having a problem dealing with one of it.

I have a URl which I suppose is an API to the service I need to work on. The URL looks like this

> http://mail.domain_name.com.au:8101/AXAIf/AXServiceIIS/xppservice.svc?wsdl

This is a password protected web service and i have the access credentials to it.

My primary requirement is:

1. To verify if the API is working
2. I need to send some data to this web service and capture the response from it.

As per my study WSDL is a defination lagugage which defines the necessary information for the web sevice.

So my question is :

1. How can I test if the API is working from above url and the Authentication credentials using PHP?

   2. Am I suppose to get the location and function from the above wsdl Url?

Can someone help me out here.And make me clear on my above queries?

That would be a great help.

Thanks in Advance. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check SoapUI, it will help a lot. https://www.soapui.org/

Comment: Is it password protected using HTTP authentication?  Is the WSDL itself password protected, or just the calls to the web service?

Comment: @Kris yes the WSDL itself is password protected